# Netty user guide echo section not echoing in telnet

Tags: netty

I am working through the netty 4.x [user guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html) and ran into a problem once I got to the echo step.

Simply replacing the discard channelRead is causing issues. Here is the DiscardServer.java

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

/**
 * Discards any incoming data.
 */
public class DiscardServer {

    private int port;

    public DiscardServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); // (1)
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); // (2)
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { // (4)
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new DiscardServerHandler());
                 }
             })
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          // (5)
             .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (6)

            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); // (7)

            // Wait until the server socket is closed.
            // In this example, this does not happen, but you can do that to gracefully
            // shut down your server.
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } else {
            port = 7676;
        }
        new DiscardServer(port).run();
    }
}
```

Here is the handler code used (successfully) for discard and printing to console:

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil;

/**
 * Handles a server-side channel.
 */
public class DiscardServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter { // (1)

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) { // (2)
        // Discard the received data silently.
//        ((ByteBuf) msg).release(); // (3)

        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        try {
            while (in.isReadable()) { // (1)
                System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
                System.out.flush();
            }
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg); // (2)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) { // (4)
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Following the guide I expected to be able to simply replace the channelRead method code with this:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.write(msg); // (1)
    ctx.flush(); // (2)
}
```

I did run the completed example code included with netty and it worked. I am trying to understand what is wrong with the example code in the guide though.